# Can not create new user record on Rails api via Postman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, devise, postman

I am creating new api app via Ruby on Rails.
So i am using `Devise` to manage my users table.

The problem when i test the api by send the request via Postman, it can not passed my model validation.

So this is my controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :json

  def create
    user = User.new(user_params)
    if user.save
      render json: user, status: 201, location: [:my, user]
    else
      render json: { errors: user.errors }, status: 422
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation,:username,:fullname,:grade)
  end

end
```

This is the data that i send to server via Postman

```
{
    "user"  : {
        "email": "test5@gmail.com",
        "password": "123456",
        "password_confirmation": "123456",
        "username": "yofoyf",
        "fullname": "narotuo sarp",
        "grade": "aaa"
    }
}
```

And i also set the header to be application/json like this

[image]

But when i click send i got errors because it can not pass my validation like this

```
Sign up

3 errors prohibited this user from being saved:

Username can't be blank
Grade can't be blank
Fullname can't be blank
```

This is my model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :username, presence: true ,uniqueness: true
  validates :grade, presence: true
  validates :fullname, presence: true

end
```

So how can i make the Postman works?
It seems like the server cannot read my username, fullname and grade record.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried sending the user as the outer level JSON object?

Comment: Set the parameters in body section of postman like this user[:email] value

Comment: @AdamRosini do you have any example?

Comment: @Navin you mean set it one by one per a record?

Comment: Yes, you have send the parameter in body section of postman one by one like user[:email] value then in next line user[:password]  123456, for each record and hit the send button.

Comment: Please let us know, is your issue is solved

Answer (score 0):

Try posting your user like this:

```
{
    "email": "test5@gmail.com",
    "password": "123456",
    "password_confirmation": "123456",
    "username": "yofoyf",
    "fullname": "narotuo sarp",
    "grade": "aaa"
}
```

Comment: Not working seems like it need :user for pass permit.

Answer (score -1):

You have send the parameter in body section of postman one by one like bellow

```
user[:email] "test5@gmail.com"  // then in next line 
user[:password] 123456
```

for each record you have to pass parameter with new request and hit the send button

Comment: I pass the data inside body via form-data like what you did but it still not working. I got `ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::ParseError`